# Haskell Data.Map Lookup not looking for all values

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to have one `Map` that maps `[Char]` to `Complex Double`.

But every time I make a lookup for certain elements of that map I don't get the result i'm expecting.

Example: searching `"h"` in `[("h",1 ),("_c",1 :+ 1),("x",2 :+ 0),("y",5)]`

```
*Main> lookup "h" (fromAscList [("h",1 ),("_c",1 :+ 1),("x",2 :+ 0),("y",5)])
Nothing
```

Example: searching `"y"` in `[("h",1 ),("_c",1 :+ 1),("x",2 :+ 0),("y",5)]`

```
*Main> lookup "y" (fromAscList [("h",1 ),("_c",1 :+ 1),("x",2 :+ 0),("y",5)])
Just (5.0 :+ 0.0)
```

I'm getting a weird behaviour from this structure.

Would be much apreciated for an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fromAscList function should be applied to an ascending list. But "h" > "_c". Your code violates this precondition, so it is not a surpruse that it does not work properly.

Comment: Thx very much... 
I thought i was going crazy...
Missread the fromAscList definition.
Thx

Comment: @TiagoLoureiro, you should use `fromList` instead if you don't know that the list is ascending--it should be faster than during first (if it's not, that's a bug).